# Why is mongodb casting a string to long automatically?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm bulk inserting some products and some of them have sku with letters and dashes and some of them are only numbers:

```
{
  "title": "My Product",
  "sku": "123456789"
}
```

For some reason, mongodb stores the sku field as a `Long` when there are no alphabetical characters. Like so:

```
{
  "title": "My Product",
  "sku": 123456789
}
```

This is how I'm inserting the data:

```js
const products = parseTree(tree); // Parsed from an XML document

const ops = products.map((product) => ({
  updateOne: {
    filter: { sku: product.sku },
    update: { $set: product },
    upsert: true,
  },
}));

await db.collection("products").bulkWrite(ops);
```

Comment: What's your Schema looks like?

Comment: How are you inserting (code details) _and_ what is the input format?

Comment: @ShivamSood I'm not using mongoose nor a schema validator, I'm using the raw mongodb driver

Comment: @prasad_ I've edited the question, there's no much more to it, really